# I want to create a object based on a original one, with the parameter path which represent only the entities I want to be in there

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that can have nested arrays of objects, as shown in the following example format:
menu: [ { name: "categoria", id: 123, products: [ { name: "produto", id: 22, items: [ { name: "cebola" }, { name: "frango" } ] }, { } ] }, { }, { } ] }, { } ]
Additionally, I also receive a parameter called "path" that contains the path to a product found within this array, for example:
path: ["0", "products", "0", "items", "1"]
I would like to create a function that, when given this path, creates a new array similar to the original array but only containing the objects specified in the path. For example, the expected response for this case would be:
response: [ { name: "categoria", id: 123, products: [ { name: "produto", id: 22, items: [ { name: "frango" } ] } ] } ]

can somebody help me?

```
createFilteredMenu(menu, path = [ "0", "products", "0"])  {
      if (path.length === 0) {
        return [];
      }
  const index = parseInt(path[0]);
      if (isNaN(index) || index < 0 || index >= menu.length) {
        return [];
      }
  const currentObject = menu[index];
      if (path.length === 1) {
        return [currentObject];
      }
      function getNestedProperty(object, key) {
        if (object && typeof object === "object" && key in object) {
          return object[key];
        }
        return [];
      }
      const nextPath = path.slice(1);
      const nextObjects = this.createFilteredMenu(getNestedProperty(currentObject, path[0]), nextPath);
      const filteredObject = { ...currentObject, [path[1]]: nextObjects };
      return [filteredObject];
    },
```

I've tried this code, but didnt work as I expected, it didn't build the nested elements

Comment: Welcome to SO, I recommend actually creating a snippet with the  `< >` icons for a [mcve]. This will assist in getting the best answers.